# SQL case-when-else statement efficiency

Tags: sql, oracle, case-when

When I use this statement;

```
UPDATE TABLE
   SET FIELD = CASE
               WHEN NAME = 'a' THEN (SELECT NO FROM TABLE_TWO WHERE NAME = 'a')
               ELSE 'x' END
 WHERE FIELD_TWO = 1
```

if `TABLE.NAME != 'a'` will the select SQL executed nevertheless?
Moreover, a little extra question, do you think it is proper to have such logic in SQL code for any given product? I think having any logic in SQL makes its coverage very difficult, and hard to maintain, what do you think?

edit: select statement only returns a single value, ignore the case where it can return multiple values, that case is not in  the scope of this question.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? In general: CASE statements do not "shortcut", so it's highly likely the nested select will be executed for each row selected by the `where` clause. But it does depend on the DBMS being used.

Comment: Currently I am using Oracle 12g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Oracle manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/expressions004.htm#SQLRF20037) claims that it *does* short-circuit evaluation:

> *Oracle Database uses **short-circuit evaluation**. For a simple `CASE` expression, the database evaluates each `comparison_expr` value only before comparing it to `expr`, rather than evaluating all comparison_expr values before comparing any of them with expr*

In your case `comparison_expr` is the `WHEN NAME = 'a'` part and if the manual is right, the database will not run the `select` if `name` has a different value.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to read and maintain, when you split it into two UPDATE-statements like this:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET FIELD = (SELECT TOP 1 NO FROM TABLE_TWO WHERE NAME = 'a')
            WHERE FIELD_TWO = 1
              AND NAME='a'
UPDATE TABLE SET FIELD = 'x' 
            WHERE FIELD_TWO = 1
            AND NAME != 'a'
```

It lets you add more cases easily and you can generalize the cases if there are more of them, like:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET FIELD = (SELECT TOP 1 NO FROM TABLE_TWO WHERE NAME = TABLE.FIELD)
            WHERE FIELD_TWO = 1
              AND NAME IN ('a','b','c')
```

Comment: I like this, since it improves the readability a lot, but it still does execute the inner select even if the conditions of the first statement were false, right?

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would use a variable so that case doesn't compute a scalar value everytime. Something like following:

```
DECLARE @myVar VARCHAR(10);

SELECT TOP 1 @myVar = NO FROM TABLE_TWO WHERE NAME = 'a';

UPDATE TABLE
   SET FIELD = CASE
               WHEN NAME = 'a' THEN @myVar
               ELSE 'x' END
 WHERE FIELD_TWO = 1
```

Comment: Question is that will that select SQL be executed regardless of the condition in case statement? It looks like that way.